# Apache: Redirect all requests to https://www.domain.tld

Tags: http, web, https, redirect, no-www

I can not find a working solution for me.

Here my settings:

```
# Redirect non-www to www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect http to https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The each parts work very well but not together.
The part for https redirection always redirect to https://domain.tld so without www, It is ignored.
Does someone know a solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing `HTTPS` and include `WWW`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}#%{HTTPS}s !^www\.([^#]+)#(?:off|on(s)) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http%2://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Should do both in one shot, otherwise you can separate the rules and probably to it this way:

```
# Rewrite to WWW
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Rewrite HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If the rewrite doesn't work for `non-www` to `www` then there's likely a VirtualHost 301 redirect somewhere else (probably in `httpd.conf`) that is set on the server... It would look similar to this:

**httpd.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

If that is set in `httpd.conf` it can override the rewrite in `.htaccess` for `non-www` to `www`.

Comment: "Doesn't work" explains nothing... what is the behavior?

Comment: ``http://domain.tld https://domain.tld and https://www.domain.tld redirect to http://www./``

``http://www.domain.tld -> 404 Page Not Found``

Comment: rewriting loop,
https part only -> ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS,
www part only  -> rewriting loop

Comment: It seems there is a problem with my hoster, in which it is possible only without www. Let's see what the support will say.
Thank you very much for your help l'L'l

Comment: I've edited the answer once again; it may not redirect to `www` though if you have a 301 redirect somewhere else (like in virtual host settings perhaps)...